# browser-sync-webpack-plugin not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browser-sync

I have configured it as instructed at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-webpack-plugin

This is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  watch: true,
  plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      server: {
        baseDir: ['dist']
      }
    })
  ]
}

module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "real-estate-2",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
  }
}
```

But when I run the webpack I got this error on terminal:
Error: Cannot find module 'browser-sync-webpack-plugin'

I have installed the browser-sync-webpack-plugin as instructed: npm install --save-dev browser-sync-webpack-plugin

Comment: Please show the contents of your project's package.json

Comment: I have updated package.json file above

Comment: I could guess the issue is in your project structure. Could you also screenshot the file tree?

Comment: this is my project file structure: https://imgur.com/a/vwMoeqJ

Comment: Sorry for asking dumb questions, but we have to double-check everything. Is there a "browser-sync-webpack-plugin" directory inside of "node_modules" directory?

Comment: I do not see it. That's what I'm wondering. All the dev dependencies I have installed do not appear in the node_modules directory.
https://imgur.com/a/VPPtRi0

Comment: 1. Make sure that your shell's working directory is your project folder
2. Try running: `npm install --only=dev`

Comment: I'm sure that
E:\GD\__Projects\Web\real-estate-2>

Comment: What does `npm install --only=dev` output?

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'browser-sync'
I have installed browser-sync in global

Comment: Please copy-paste or screenshot the whole log from `npm install --only=dev`

Comment: After I installed browser-sync in local it worked.
Thanks you very much. I just started learning to use webpack and faced many difficulties. Can you please give me facebook so that I can contact you. Again thank you so much ^^.

Comment: Sure. Facebook: nikis05, if you have Telegram, it is preferred: @nikis05. In fact you should try to avoid using global dependencies at all. This will give you very little overhead, but at the same time transparency and explicitness of the whole dependency management thing will increase. I also advise you to use yarn instead of npm.

Answer (score -2):

```
npm install --save-dev browser-sync
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: Why there is need of browser-sync pakcage as `loadash` is the only dependency required for browser-sync-webpack-plugin. 
link -> `https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-webpack-plugin`.